# What is wrong with this procedure-writing Angular momentum operator in spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, quantum-mechanics

I am trying to write the first component of the quantum angular momentum operator  $L_1$ in spherical coordinates.
$$L_1=x_2p_3-x_3p_2=-i\hbar (x_2\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_3}-x_3\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_2})=$$

The defining equations of the spherical coordinates are:
$x_1=r \sin\theta \cos\varphi,x_2=r\sin\theta\sin\varphi, x_3=r\cos\theta\tag{1}$
Then using the chain rule:

\begin{align}
L_1
&=-i\hbar (x_2\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_3}-x_3\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_2})\\
&=-i\hbar \Big[r\sin\theta\sin\varphi\left(
\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x_3}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}
+\dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial x_3}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
+\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_3}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\; -r\cos\theta\ \left(
\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x_2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}
+\dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial x_2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
+\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}\right)
\Big] \tag{2}
\end{align}

Using (1):

$\dfrac {\partial r}{\partial x_3}=\dfrac {1}{\frac{\partial x_3}{\partial r}}=\dfrac {1}{\cos \theta}$

$\dfrac {\partial \theta}{\partial x_3}=\dfrac {1}{\frac{\partial x_3}{\partial \theta}}=\dfrac {-1}{r \sin \theta}$

$\dfrac {\partial \varphi}{\partial x_3}=0$

$\dfrac {\partial r}{\partial x_2}=\dfrac {1}{\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial r}}=\dfrac {1}{\sin \theta \sin \varphi}$

$\dfrac {\partial \theta}{\partial x_2}=\dfrac {1}{\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial \theta}}=\dfrac {1}{r \cos \theta \sin \varphi}$

$\dfrac {\partial \varphi}{\partial x_2}=\dfrac {1}{\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial \varphi}}=\dfrac {1}{r \sin \theta \cos \varphi}$

Plugging these results in (2):
$$L_1=-i\hbar [r\tan\theta\sin\varphi
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}
-\sin \varphi\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
-r \dfrac{\cot\theta}{\sin \varphi}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}
-\dfrac{1}{\sin \varphi}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
-\dfrac{\cot \theta}{ \cos \varphi}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}
] \tag{3}$$

But the result should be
$$L_1=+i\hbar [\sin \varphi\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
+\cos \varphi \cot \theta \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}
] \tag{4}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Semiclassical  Thanks I fixed that

Comment: The basic issue is that you're computing partial derivatives as reciprocals. That's not a good idea, because it leads to treating certain variables as fixed when they're not. The way out of this is to explicitly write $r,\varphi,\theta$ as functions of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and compute the first partials directly. (In particular, check the cases where you differentiate with respect to angles.)

Comment: I suspected that, but I did it because doing the way you suggested seemed very long and I was sure I'd seen derivates calculated like this somewhere; maybe there is some case where I can use $\dfrac{\partial x }{\partial y }= 1/ \dfrac{\partial y }{\partial x }$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When enough variables are involved, partial derivatives need a disambiguation as to what is held constant in their definition, e.g. $\left(\tfrac{\partial u}{\partial v}\right)_w$ holds $w$ constant. In particular, $\left(\tfrac{\partial u}{\partial v}\right)\left(\tfrac{\partial v}{\partial u}\right)\ne1$ when we use different conventions in these derivatives.

A simpler version of your mistake is found in planar polar coordinates with $4$ variables $x,\,y,\,r,\,\theta$. For example, compare$$\left(\tfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right)_\theta=\left(\tfrac{\partial r\cos\theta}{\partial r}\right)_\theta=\cos\theta=\tfrac{x}{r}$$with$$\left(\tfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)_y=\left(\tfrac{\partial\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\partial x}\right)_y=\tfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\tfrac{x}{r}.$$These aren't reciprocals; in fact, they're equal. (Physics has another famous example of what you'd think would be reciprocals in fact being equal; it's the basis of a lot of relativity "paradoxes".)

The [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) is another important example of such "gotchas". If $f(x,\,y,\,z)=0$ then$$\prod_\text{cyc}\left(\tfrac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z=-1$$(note the minus sign).

Comment: So with 2 or 3 variables the rule is valid?

Comment: I am sure I have seen they use this reciprocal rule somewhere

Comment: @mathlover See edit (a typo has since been corrected).

Comment: In your last example the we don't have a explicit function, Isn't there a case in which having an explicit function, the reciprocal rule is true? Maybe with only 2 variables?

Comment: @mathlover You mean like $x=r\cos\theta,\,y=r\sin\theta,\,r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\,\theta=\operatorname{atan2}(y,\,x)$?

Comment: But, that is the case where you just show the rule does not hold. I was asking if there is any general case in which the derivative of x with respect to y is in fact the reciprocal of the derivative of y with respect to x, like single variable function, perhaps?

Comment: @mathlover If $y$ is an invertible function of $x$ alone, $dy/dx=1/(dx/dy)$, but those aren't partial derivatives. You want something like $y=f(x,\,z)$ where for fixed $z$ we can invert viz. $x=g(y,\,z)$, whence $\partial x/\partial y,\,\partial y/\partial x$ both assume $z$ is held fixed.

Comment: That must be it, I guess I believed it worked also por partial derivatives.Then to find all those 6 partial derivatives I need, do I have to write explicitly r, theta and phi in terms of x1,x2,x3? It is long since arcos and arctan of compound function show up, isn't there a faster method?

Comment: @mathlover Borrow Eqs. (98)-(100) [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html). (In fact, for $L_1$ you don't even need (98).)

Comment: Once I have $L_1$ writen in shperical coordinates, If I do the same for$ L_2$ and $L_3$, I get $L= L_1 \hat i+ L_2\hat j+ L_3\hat k$ but a expression written in spherical coordinates should not be in terms of the cartesian  unit vectors, should it? Is this really written in spherical coordinates or it is a sort of mixture?

Comment: @mathlover $L_1$ is one of $3$ Cartesian parts, but you want a formula for it in terms of $r,\,\theta,\,\varphi,\,\partial_r,\,\partial_\theta,\,\partial_\varphi$, which is obtainable from my suggested equations, together with the formula for $L_1$ with which you started.

Comment: Yeah ,all good here, I just wandered if writting $L$ with the cartesian unit vectors is really $L$ in cartesian coordinates, since I am not using the spherical unit vectors

Comment: @mathlover You're confusing two coordinate system choices we can make independently: $L$-space coordinates and $x$-space coordinates.

Comment: Sorry I typo I meant that writting L with the cartesian unit vectors but with the components written in terms of $(r,\theta, \phi)$, that is L=$L_1(r,\theta, \phi)\hat i+L_2(r,\theta, \phi)\hat j+L_3(r,\theta, \phi)\hat k$ doesn't really  seem to be L in spherical  coordinates. It should be something like L=$L_r(r,\theta, \phi)\hat e_r +L_{\theta}(r,\theta, \phi)\hat e_{\theta}+L_{\phi}(r,\theta, \phi)\hat e_{\phi}$

Comment: @mathlover Well, we're expressing $L$-space Cartesian coordinates in terms of $x$-space spherical coordinates. Those are two independent choices. If you want $L_\phi$ etc., I recommend asking a new question.